# The function call inside the redux action doesnot get executed

Tags: reactjs, redux, google-cloud-firestore, thunk

I'm trying my first react application with redux, along with Thunk as middle ware. When calling the action from one of the components, the action is hit but the code inside the action return is not executed. I have no clue what I'm missing here. I'm also using Firestore to get the data.

```
    export const getBikeTypes = () => {
    console.log('outside return')
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFireBase, getFireStore }) => {
        console.log('inside return')
        const firestore = getFireStore();
        firestore.collection('BikeTypes').get()
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
                return response
            }).then(() => {
                dispatch({ type: 'GET_BIKETYPES' });
            }).catch((err) => {
                dispatch({ type: 'GET_BIKETYPES_FAIL', err });
            })
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you share the configuration code where you've hooked up the thunk middleware to your store?

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by action? Can you see the "inside return' and response console.logs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should dispatch action with the payload once you get the response.

```js
const firestore = getFireStore();
firestore.collection('BikeTypes').get()
  .then((response) => {
     dispatch({ type: 'GET_BIKETYPES', payload: response })
  })
```